# how to render html template in javascript from flask

Tags: javascript

and my script is :

```js
const starting = 3;
let time = starting;

countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

setInterval(updateCountdown,1000);

function updateCountdown(){
    let seconds  = time;
    countdownEl.innerHTML = `${seconds}`;
    if (time > 0) {
        time--;
    }
    
    if (time == 0) {
        window.location="{{ url_for('disinfect') }}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add details of what the expected result and any / all errors are with this please?

Comment: In head tag of index.html include the js file you want to render